# Liquibase generateChangeLog can't handle the same table name in different schemas

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

I am using MSSQL and evaluating Liquibase to use for migrations.  So, I wanted to generate my first changelog using generateChangeLog.  My database has two schemas: the default schema and another called 'blah'.  I have a table in each schema with the same table name: `test1`.  I ran:

`liquibase --dataOutputDirectory=./data/ --schemas=blah,dbo --changeLogFile=changelog.mssql.sql --includeSchema=true generateChangeLog`

It completed and I looked at the generated SQL:

```
-- liquibase formatted sql

-- changeset bmccord2:1604068236633-1
CREATE TABLE blah.test1 (id int NOT NULL, name varchar(255), CONSTRAINT PK__test1__3213E83F4F883C7C PRIMARY KEY (id));

-- changeset bmccord2:1604068236633-2
INSERT INTO blah.test1 (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Brian'),(2, 'Kim');;

-- changeset bmccord2:1604068236633-3
CREATE TABLE dbo.test1 (id int NOT NULL, name varchar(255), CONSTRAINT PK__test1__3213E83F6FD50901 PRIMARY KEY (id));

-- changeset bmccord2:1604068236633-4
INSERT INTO dbo.test1 (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Brian'),(2, 'Kim');;
```

At first, it looks ok, but then I noticed that the data being inserted into the blah.test1 table is not the data that is actually in that table.  The data in that table is:

```
"id","name"
"1","Miranda"
"2","Kyle"
```

So, it is using the second table's data for both tables.  It is also only generating one .csv file in the data folder.

Obviously, this isn't my real database.  I simplified the problem down to the smallest thing that causes the problem.

Is there any way to make this work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Checking their [forum](https://forum.liquibase.org/t/generatechangelog-for-multiple-schemas-in-mysql/3168) they state that:

> The way that Liquibase is designed, it only works with a single schema at a time.

If it fits your use case you could try to define two separate migrations and apply them one by one, e.g:

```
liquibase --dataOutputDirectory=./data/ --schemas=blah --changeLogFile=changelog.blah.mssql.sql --includeSchema=true generateChangeLog
liquibase --dataOutputDirectory=./data/ --schemas=dbo --changeLogFile=changelog.dbo.mssql.sql --includeSchema=true generateChangeLog
```

or if you would prefer to apply the exact same changelog for both database you can call it twice with the same changeLogFile. In that case only the --schemas needs to be adjusted. (`--schemas=dbo` and `--schemas=blah`)